# Encoding error on Rails 2.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding

Our setup includes the following:

- Ruby 1.9.1
- Rails 2.3.4
- Postgres 9
- Linux

When trying to output some UTF-8 data from the DB as CSV, Rails throws the following error:

```
ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII):
  haml (2.2.5) lib/sass/plugin/rails.rb:19:in `process'
  <internal:prelude>:8:in `synchronize'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p431/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p431/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p431/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

The same error occurs both when running through Webrick using `script/server` and through Passenger.

The funny part is that, on the almost same setup on my local machine, using the same database and the same request (so with the same data in the resultset), it doesn't crash.

Any ideas?

Comment: If your local machine is almost the same then perhaps the clue is in the difference? Also ruby 1.9.1 was sort beta-ish. First widely used ruby 1.9 was really 1.9.2. I'd also recommend switching to a more recent version of rails 2.3 - the earlier versions were released before ruby 1.9.2

Comment: I forgot to add, previously the app was working on (almost) the same setup on another server as well, using identical Ruby 1.9.1. We were carefully trying to keep identical ruby and gem versions when migrating to another server. I have 1.9.2 on my local machine, but I doubt it is causing the error.

Comment: Well if it doesn't work on 2 machines with 1.9.1 and it does work on a machine with 1.9.2 i would consider the ruby version very relevant (unless there are other more relevant changes between the working and non working machines), especially as the encoding stuff was one of the major area being stabilised between 1.9.1 and 1.9.2

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. It was working on one 1.9.1 machine, moved to another 1.9.1 machine where it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving to Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 2.3.14 indeed did solve the issue. Thanks to Frederick!